# Trying to understand some concepts of Measure Theory for Statistical Inference

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistical-inference

I have the next set of measures $\{P_{\theta},\theta\in \Theta\}$ for a parameter space $\Theta$. I found the next statement in a book:

$$\boxed{\text{We assume that the measures }P_{\theta}\;\text{are all dominated by some }\sigma\text{-finite } \text{measure }Q,\;\text{so that the density function }f_{X}(\cdot;\theta)\;\text{under }P_{\theta}\;\text{of }X\;\text{with respect to }Q\;\text{exists. Formally, }f_{X}(\cdot;\theta)\;\text{is the Radon-Nikodym derivate of }P_{\theta}\;\text{with respect to }Q.}$$

I have never been in a Measure Theory class, so for me most of the concepts are new. I have try to study myself but I end up with the same questions.

Is there a way to understand the statement without going to the details? I just want to move on to study statistical inference.

Will I have some problems understanding some concepts of statistics if I don't understand the concepts related to the statement presentend?

Comment: This is a fairly deep result (existence of Radon-Nikodym derivative). Just read the statement as you have a bunch of probability densities and move on (assuming you learned about densities in your elementary probability class, how you compute stuff with them and their properties ).

Comment: Yes, I have a solid background in probability distributions, both univariate and multivariate. But, will I have some problems understanding some concepts of statistics if I don't understand the concepts related to the statement presentend?

Comment: I doubt it. I would suggest you move forward and if you encounter anything you don't understand, just ask here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll move forward.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: It might be a sign that the book assumes a good deal of measure theory and this will not be the last stumbling block.